# Leer Ñ de un txt con FileInputStream

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy intentando leer **EÑES** de un archivo de texto con un FileInputStream sin éxito. Cuando el FileInputStream lee una Ñ, me la detecta como dos caracteres (195 y 145 para Ñ mayúscula, 195 y 177 para ñ minúscula). Me tengo que ceñir al FileInputStream, no puedo usar otro tipo de stream... ¿cuál es mi error? ¿cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

**Código**:

```
public class Lector {
    public static void leerEnes(File archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
        int valorLeido = fis.read();
        char caracter = 0;
        
        while(valorLeido != -1){
            System.out.println(valorLeido);
            System.out.println((char) valorLeido);
            valorLeido = fis.read();
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File archivo = new File("/Users/pherrero/Documents/repositorios/dam_ad2021/tema2/leyendoEnes/enes.txt");
        try {
            Lector.leerEnes(archivo);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Salida**:

```
195
Ã
145
‘
195
Ã
177
±
```

Comment: Probablemente vas a tener que jugar con el encoding. Cual es el encoding del archivo que estás leyendo? UTF-8 o ascii? (o algún otro)

Comment: Pues es un archivo de texto con encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el archivo es UTF-8 necesita 2 bytes para caracteres extendidos como la `ñ` y un byte para caracteres normales como la `a`, así que la idea es leer dos bytes o uno según el caso. En el código se evalúa contra 127 que es el código más alto del ASCII estándar.

```
public static void leerEnes(File archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);

       
        int valorLeido;

        while (true) {

            valorLeido = fis.read();
            if (valorLeido < 0) break;

            if(valorLeido <= 127){
                // es un caracter de un byte
                System.out.println(valorLeido);
                System.out.println((char)valorLeido);
            }else{
                // es un caracter de 2 bytes así que hay que leer el siguiente
                int aux = fis.read();
                

                // extracción código del caracter
                // según la codificación UTF-8 el primer byte (valorLeido)
                // inicia con 110xxxxx así que se remueve el 110 para dejar solo 
                // el valor númerico xxxxx
                // el segundo byte (aux) inicia con 10xxxxxx así que remueve el 10
                // y se hace un desplamiento de bits para dejarlos concatenados
                // en la variable codigoCaracter
                int codigoCaracter = (valorLeido & 0b11111) << 6 | (aux & 0b111111);

                System.out.println(codigoCaracter);
                System.out.println((char)codigoCaracter);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: O usar clases más arriba que te permitan especificar el encoding del stream y así no hacer ese trabajo "a pie". Por ejemplo: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: Sí @eftshift0, gracias. Pero el requerimiento del OP es hacerlo con FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más facil y correcto es usar un FileReader pasandole el charset. En concreto

```
FileReader(String fileName, Charset charset)
```

Haciendo integración he encontrado muchas historias de terror. En ese caso no hay más remedio que leer byte a byte hasta CR/LF e intentar descifrar. Esto está en producción:

```
   // En el mismo archivo mezcla Windows-1252 (ascii extendido) y utf8
   line = new String(bytes, 0, n, "Windows-1252");
   // System.out.println(line);
   if (line.contains("Ã") || line.contains("Â")) {
       line = new String(bytes, 0, n, "utf8");
       // System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Muchas risas con el usuario Jos� CastaÂo